# UIButton resize with animation

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, uiimage, uibutton

I'm creating a menu and I want the buttons to "pop" I guess on the screen. Basically I want to start at 0px dimensions and then go up to the full size of the buttons. I can animate the alpha and the position if I want to but can't do the dimensions and I think its because its an image on the button.

If I do a UIButtonTypeRoundRect you can see the button being animated behind the image but the image is static.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 0, 0);
button.alpha = 0;
[self.view addSubview:button];
CGRect frame = button.frame;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"button" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
button.alpha = 1;
frame.size.width += 53;
frame.size.height += 53;
button.frame = frame;
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

So the Alpha works but the resize doesn't. I've also played with stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth to try and give it context or something but to no avail.

Cheers for your help.

Comment: Have you tried making the button `Scale To Fill`?

Comment: yup, remember trying that at one stage. Who robbed you?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Could you try using the following code instead?

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5);
button.alpha = 0.0f;

[UIView beginAnimations:@"button" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
     button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
     button.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Your button should start slightly larger and then shrink back down. If this scales properly, just adjust the scalefactor before and after to suit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look and get back to you.

Comment: That didn't work straight away. Button = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5); threw an error. But basically you can do the button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5,1.5); and it animates a scale increase like I needed. Thanks :)

Comment: Great stuff - I've amended the code sample for anyone else who might want to use it

Answer (score 6):

**Updated for Swift:**

You can insert this in whatever IBAction you've got tied to a button to animate it when it's touched.

```
    // animate button
    // play with the scale (1.25) to adjust to your liking
    yourButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.25, 1.25)
    yourButton.alpha = 0.0

    UIView.beginAnimations("yourButton", context: nil)
    // play with the animationDuration to adjust to your liking
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.25)
    yourButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
    yourButton.alpha =  1.0
```